# Adding email in Django's admin user creation

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm having trouble figuring out how to add the email field to the admin panel's create user page (Django 3.2). I've managed to get a custom field to show but keep running into errors when I attempt to add email in the same way.

[image]

**accounts/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    
    # Short list displayed on admin/accounts/customuser page
    list_display = ['email', 'username', 'company', 'is_staff']

    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
        (None, {'fields': ('company',)}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.add_fieldsets + (
        (None, {'fields': ('company',)}),
    )

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

**accounts/forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('company',)


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields
```

Comment: What is not working with `fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('company', 'email')`?

Comment: It doesn't change anything. No error. No email field. Nothing.

Comment: What does your CustomUser model look like?

Comment: Question is: why? The add form focuses on creating the account, after that you can edit additional fields and it redirects to it even. In case the username is not unique or password doesn't satisfy validators, you added extra data you can fill out again. Anyway, you need to modify the `add_fieldsets`.